# Static Library Dependency Must Be "Cleaned" Each Build

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

I'm creating a game for both OSX and iOS simultaneously. I have a workspace with 3 projects:

1. **CORE** is a static library with 2 targets: one for OSX and one for iOS. It contains 99.99% of all the code.
2. **OSX** is a project which uses the library and builds the OSX app
3. **iOS** is a project which uses the library and builds the iOS app

The **OSX** project works perfectly. I press build and it runs great.

Strangely, the **CORE** project shows a red product for iOS target. I've linked this target to the **iOS** project, and it works fine... except when I make a change to the **CORE** library, the change is not reflected in the app unless I clean the **iOS** project first. In other words, *even if I explicitly rebuild the **CORE** library, it still doesn't work; I have to clean the **iOS** project before the core changes take effect*.

Screenshot:
[image]

Desired functionality: just like with the OSX app, I should simply be able to press "build" and any changes to the **CORE** library will be compiled and deployed into the app.

The problem appears to be the fact that the place where XCode **THINKS** the libAftermathCore-iOS.a file **should** be:
[image]

Is not where it is actually built to:
[image]

Notice that the folder name **is** correct for the OSX library, but not the iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should add your lib to the AftermathIOS target dependencies: Click on project -> choose the target -> Build Phases -> Target Dependencies

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that, sorry. When I click the + button in Target Dependencies, there's nothing in the window that appears (it says "no filter results").

Comment: And what about OSX project? Is there such dependency?

Comment: No. The OSX project has no dependency listed. Also, this is not a dependency build problem. Even if I rebuild the iOS library the problem still happens. The only way to fix it is to CLEAN the iOS library. Then, it doesn't matter what I build, it works from there.

Comment: You can create a temporary hack: make custom build phase "Run Script" and clean your library from there.

Comment: Hm, it looks like the problem is that the library is not building into the correct folder on iOS, but it is on OSX. I've updated the OP with screenshots.

Comment: So why don't you set the correct location manually? But I see it looks like disabled on the screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I ended up solving this by changing the **Per-configuration Build Products Path** from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Which now means that all 4 targets build into the same folder:

[image]